# What is the point of graphics context in xcb_copy_area?

Tags: c, x11, xcb

The function `xcb_copy_area` by my understanding essentially copies a region from one xcb_drawable to another. I'm not sure then why it would also take a graphics context as a parameter, seeing as the source of the copy has presumably already been drawn or rendered. What is the use of this parameter in this case?

It's worth noting that my understanding of graphics contexts are not great but there aren't many resources on explaining them. I'm assuming this is an issue with my mental model of what's going on within xcb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant docs: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#requests:CopyArea

The text description contains this (emphasis mine and original emphasis and a link were lost):

> If the dst-drawable is a window with a background other than None, these corresponding destination regions are **tiled (with plane-mask of all ones and function Copy) with that background**. Regardless of tiling and whether the destination is a window or a pixmap, if **graphics-exposures in gc** is True, then GraphicsExposure events for all corresponding destination regions are generated.

So, my understanding is: The GC is used to draw the background of the window and this is where most of its properties are used.

The doc says explicitly which GC components are used:

> GC components: function, plane-mask, subwindow-mode, graphics-exposures, clip-x-origin, clip-y-origin, clip-mask

- I guess that `function` and `plane-mask` specify how the source and target are "combined". So, `CopyArea` can not only copy, but do all the other (weird) things that are possible with a GC.
- `subwindow-mode` says what happens with subwindows. It is possible to clip them out or to draw over them.
- `graphics-exposures` is about events that are generated in response to drawing
- `clip-x-origin`, `clip-y-origin`, and `clip-mask` clearly are about clipping the drawing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. Best docs I've seen yet for xcb.